# Optimize bitflag check

Tags: c, binary, flags, bitflags

How can I optimize the following code?

```
   ( (kbd_flags & KBD_FLAG_SHIFT) && !(kbd_flags & KBD_FLAG_CAPS))
|| (!(kbd_flags & KBD_FLAG_SHIFT) &&  (kbd_flags & KBD_FLAG_CAPS))
```

Basically, I want to check if either KBD_FLAG_SHIFT or KBD_FLAG_CAPS is set, but not both.

Comment: that's not what that code does. It checks if any flags have been set.

Comment: You're totally right, let me correct it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would like to share my solution after doing some research. Zodoh's expression can be simplified to

```
kbd_flags & KBD_FLAG_SHIFT
    ? !(kbd_flags & KBD_FLAG_CAPS)
    :   kbd_flags & KBD_FLAG_CAPS
```

(Omitting unneeded parentheses and the `true` and `false` expressions)

Another interesting way I figured out is the following:

```
x = kbd_flags & (KBD_FLAG_SHIFT | KBD_FLAG_CAPS);
return x && (x & x - 1) == 0;
```

This works because of the way two's complement notation is designed. As an example, if `kbd_flags` is set to `001000`, `x - 1` will be `000111` and `001000 & 000111` is `000000`. As a result, `000000` is equal to `0`, thus returning `true`. The first `x` expression makes sure that the "no bit set" case is excluded.

It will also work with more than only two bit flags:

```
#define A 0x01
#define B 0x02
#define C 0x04
#define D 0x08
#define E 0x10
#define F 0x20

x = flags & (A | B | C | D | E | F);
return x && (x & x - 1) == 0;
```

Here, the expression `x && (x & x - 1) == 0` will be `true` if and only if one of the flags `A` through `F` is set.

A quick test (`f` being the integer holding the flags to test for):

```
int f, x;
for (f = 0; f <= F + 1; f++) {
    x = f & (A | B | C | D | E | F);
    printf("0x%02x %d%d%d%d%d%d -> %d\n", f
        , (f & A) == A, (f & B) == B, (f & C) == C
        , (f & D) == D, (f & E) == E, (f & F) == F
        , x && (x & x - 1) == 0);
}
```

This code will output the follwing:

```
0x00 000000 -> 0
0x01 100000 -> 1
0x02 010000 -> 1
0x03 110000 -> 0
0x04 001000 -> 1
0x05 101000 -> 0
0x06 011000 -> 0
0x07 111000 -> 0
0x08 000100 -> 1
0x09 100100 -> 0
0x0a 010100 -> 0
0x0b 110100 -> 0
0x0c 001100 -> 0
0x0d 101100 -> 0
0x0e 011100 -> 0
0x0f 111100 -> 0
0x10 000010 -> 1
0x11 100010 -> 0
0x12 010010 -> 0
0x13 110010 -> 0
0x14 001010 -> 0
0x15 101010 -> 0
0x16 011010 -> 0
0x17 111010 -> 0
0x18 000110 -> 0
0x19 100110 -> 0
0x1a 010110 -> 0
0x1b 110110 -> 0
0x1c 001110 -> 0
0x1d 101110 -> 0
0x1e 011110 -> 0
0x1f 111110 -> 0
0x20 000001 -> 1
0x21 100001 -> 0
```

As you can see, `x && (x & x - 1) == 0` is `true` iff one bit is set.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

```
(kbd_flags & KBD_FLAG_SHIFT) ? ((kbd_flags & KBD_FLAG_CAPS)? false : true) : ((kbd_flags & KBD_FLAG_CAPS)? true : false)
```

Else is you know how to use the bits you can use the XOR operator ^.

```
A = 0000 0001
B = 0000 0000
A ^ B = 0000 0001

A = 0000 0000
B = 0000 0001
A ^ B = 0000 0001

A = 0000 0000
B = 0000 0000
A ^ B = 0000 0000

A = 0000 0001
B = 0000 0001
A ^ B = 0000 0000
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean regarding "you can use the XOR operator". Can you explain?

Comment: the XOR operator is the '^' symbol in C. You can use it to compare bit as it's explain right after (with A and B). Like this you can check if you got the right number.

Are your macros boolean or integers ?

Comment: I'm aware of the XOR operator in C, I just don't understand how I can use XOR to solve my problem. The macros are bit flags (unsigned integers), `KBD_FLAG_SHIFT` is 0x01 (01b) and 0x02 (10b).

Comment: and what is the type of kbd_flags ?

You do a & so you will obtain a value for (kbd_flags & KBD_FLAG_SHIFT) and (kbd_flags & KBD_FLAG_CAPS)

if you do !(condition) that's mean that condition have to be zero (or false, but false = 0).
So you will have something like :

((1) && !(0)) || (!(0) && (1))

now if you use ^ you will have those 4 cases :
1^0 0^1 0^0 1^1
only 1^0 and 0^1 will return 1 (=true) and pass.

with your code it could be something like this :
(kbd_flags & KBD_FLAG_SHIFT) ^ (kbd_flags & KBD_FLAG_CAPS)

Answer (score 0):

To answer more clearly.

```
(kbd_flags & KBD_FLAG_SHIFT) ^ (kbd_flags & KBD_FLAG_CAPS)
```

This should work.

Comment: In my opinion, this does not work. Due to readability, lets replace `kbd_flags`, `KBD_FLAG_SHIFT` and `KBD_FLAG_CAPS` with `f`, `A` and `B`, respectively.

If `f` is `11b` (`A` is `01b` and `B` is `10b`), then `(f & A)` will be `01b` and `(f & B)` will be `10b`. As a result, `(f & A) ^ (f & B)` will be `11b`, which is evaluated as `true`. But it should be `false`, because both flags are set.

Comment: So if you find the possible results you can maybe add != 11b or something like this ?

at this point it's begin to not answer your question... Well it would have work with booleans or 0 1 values.

Comment: Yes it would work with boolean values, but the question was related to bit flags. The expression "is bit flag A or B set, but not both" cannot be solved like that in my opinion.

Comment: You are totally right. Sorry for my misunderstanding of the problem.